# What does the acronym "КПЗ" stand for?

Tags: существительные

e.g. Российского студента жестоко избили в КПЗ в Канаде

Comment: There is an extensive collection of Russian abbreviations at http://abbr.ru.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

КПЗ stands for “камера предварительного заключения” (holding cell).

see also [Изолятор временного содержания](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) in Wikipedia (in Russian)